# How to solve dyld: Library not loaded error in a python wrapper for a Myo

Tags: python, dyld, rpath, myo

So I'm tinkering around with a Myo Armband. And I found out that there are some Python wrappers / bindings for it (https://github.com/smartin015/MYO-python). However, I'm getting an error when I try to run the examples.

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/myo.framework/Versions/A/myo
  Referenced from: /Users/[usr]/Documents/myo/MYO-python-master_two/./PyMyo
  Reason: image not found
```

I've gone over here to read up on what an @rpath is: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html

And I've been looking up other similar questions on StackOverflow. But so far, I'm not really sure where to start solving this.

So, what does "Reason: Image not found", mean? And how should I solve this error?

I'm running OSX 10.10.1, and just using the standard stock python that shipped w/ it 2.7.6, and its running out of /usr/bin/python

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welp. That was an easy fix.

Grab a copy of myo.framework out of the SDK, and paste it into /Library/Frameworks

Didn't think it would be that straightforward. Leaving this answer here for future reference.